# How to make Jpa repository work in unit tests and configuration?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I've created 2 entity classes that are connected with each other. I've also made a simple service, rest controller, configuration class, unit test and method with @Scheduled annotation. Service class looks like this:

```java
@Service
public class EntityService {

    @Autowired
    private Entity1Repository entity1Repository;

    @Autowired
    private Entity2Repository entity2Repository;

    public void saveEntity1() {
        entity1Repository.save(new Entity1(new Entity2("")));

        entity2Repository.save(new Entity2(""));
        entity1Repository.save(new Entity1(entity2Repository.findAll().get(0)));
    }
}
```

Configuration class has method:

```java
@Bean
public CommandLineRunner test(EntityService service) {
    return args -> service.saveEntity1();
}
```

Rest controller, unit test and @Scheduled method are similar to the configuration, they just call saveEntity1 method from the service class.

The problem is that saveEntity1 method throws exception:

```
org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: com.example.test.Entity2
```

Every time it's not called from rest controller.

After changing cascade to `CascadeType.MERGE` I was able to execute:

```java
entity2Repository.save(new Entity2(""));
entity1Repository.save(new Entity1(entity2Repository.findAll().get(0)));
```

in EntityService from configuration etc without throwing an exception, but the line:

```java
entity1Repository.save(new Entity1(new Entity2("")));
```

was still throwing exception.

My goal is to be able to use my service from rest controller, configuration, unit test etc

Here are my entity classes:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "entity1")
public class Entity1 implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @JoinColumn(name = "entity2_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    @ManyToOne(optional = false, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Entity2 entity2;

    public Entity1() {
    }

    public Entity1(Entity2 ent) {
        this.entity2 = ent;
    }

    public Entity1(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Entity2 getEntity2Id() {
        return entity2;
    }

    public void setEntity2Id(Entity2 entity2Id) {
        this.entity2 = entity2Id;
    }

}
```

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "entity2")
public class Entity2 implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String str;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "entity2")
    private List<Entity1> entity1List;

    public Entity2() {
    }

    public Entity2(String str) {
        this.str = str;
    }

    public Entity2(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getStr() {
        return str;
    }

    public void setStr(String str) {
        this.str = str;
    }

    public List<Entity1> getEntity1List() {
        return entity1List;
    }

    public void setEntity1List(List<Entity1> entity1List) {
        this.entity1List = entity1List;
    }
}
```